# What should I expect from following code

Tags: c

I am learning C and I have written the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

double *g = calloc(10, sizeof(double));
double h[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

printf("Size of g: %d\n", sizeof(g));
printf("Size of h: %d\n", sizeof(h));
}
```

I am under the impression that both `g` and `h` are double arrays of length 10, and since each double is 8 bytes, `sizeof(g)` and `sizeof(h)` should equal 80.
However, I get the following response:

```
Size of g: 8
Size of h: 80
```

What I am missing and why is `sizeof(g)` 8 here?

Comment: `sizeof(g)` is equal to `sizeof(double*)` and since it returned 8, it means addresses in your system are 64 bits long.

Answer (score 4):

g is a pointer to a double. In 64 bit code a pointer is 8 bytes long.
h is an array of 10 doubles so the size of h is 10 * 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

`g` is a pointer to a `double`. `h` is an array of 10 `doubles`. So, you should expect different results from `sizeof(h)` and `sizeof(g)`. Looks like your system is 64-bit (pointers are 8-byte long).

Btw, `sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is different from `int` and likely different from `unsigned int` and so you should use the appropriate type specifier for it, `%zu`, not `%d` or `%u`.

Answer (score 2):

For static arrays, defined in the current scope, `sizeof` returns the size of memory which an array occupies — i.e. `number_of_elements * sizeof(element)` (but if you pass a static array to a function it is automatically converted to a pointer). For dynamic arrays (i.e. pointers), on the other hand, it always returns the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`double *g`:: **g** is a pointer that means it will store the address. To store an address, **g** needs `8 Bytes (64-Bit)`. So `sizeof(g) = 8 Bytes`. `sizeof(g)` will yield the **same result** even if you declare `char *g` or `float *g` cuz in all the cases **g** would need to store the address.

On the other hand, `double h[]` (with 10 elements) would need `8 (sizeof(double)) * 10 (Num_Of_Elements)` i.e., `sizeof(h) = 80 Bytes`.